# Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Book) Chapter 7 (3rd Edition) - No route matches [POST] "/signup"

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm getting an 'No route matches [POST] "/signup"' error when in Chapter 7, I try to submit the signup form.

These are my routes:

```
root_path   GET /   static_pages#home
help_path   GET /help(.:format) static_pages#help
about_path  GET /about(.:format)    static_pages#about
contact_path    GET /contact(.:format)  static_pages#contact
signup_path GET /signup(.:format)   users#new
login_path  GET /login(.:format)    sessions#new
logout_path GET /logout(.:format)   sessions#destroy
users_path  GET /users(.:format)    users#index
            POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path   GET /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
            PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
            PUT /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
            DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
sessions_path   POST    /sessions(.:format) sessions#create
new_session_path    GET /sessions/new(.:format) sessions#new
session_path    DELETE  /sessions/:id(.:format) sessions#destroy
```

This is my Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to users_path(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
end

end
```

And this is the view where the signup gets posted from:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your resources at the top of the routes.rb file, here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

    root 'static_pages#home'

    match '/signup'           , to: 'users#new'           , via: 'get'
    match '/login'            , to: 'sessions#new'        , via: 'get'
    match '/logout'           , to: 'sessions#destroy'    , via: 'delete'
    match '/help'             , to: 'static_pages#help'   , via: 'get'
    match '/about'            , to: 'static_pages#about'  , via: 'get'
    match '/contact'          , to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

Instead of:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

end
```

Comment: I added the path do the form with a url hash and it worked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 7 doesn't have any references to sessions.
That happens in Chapter 8.

This is how the routes look like at the end of Chapter 7.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```